# Clear Windows "Run" box cache

Tags: windows, cache, run-dialog

One thing that I use almost every minute is the Windows Run box (WINDOWS+R). It let's you type a path and auto-completes it really quickly so that you can jump to any dir in no time.

My problem is that I recently swapped disks and re-organized content so a few of the drive letters changed while most (but not all) the dir structure stayed the same. Now the auto-complete is giving me a lot of old results that don't physically exist anymore and it's not only annoying but the advantage of speed is not there anymore because I now have to check for old results in my auto-complete!

How can I clear that auto-complete's cache?

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not talking about how to clear the last run items from the Windows Start menu. This is completely different. What I'm talking about auto-completes directories in the file system and is "remembering" old auto-completed paths (which are NOT programs, just paths).

Comment: I thought that the autocomplete cache just selected from the last run items and so they were the same thing. Sorry if that's not the case. I also just cleared the recent documents checkbox in the taskbar properties and that didn't work either... I am on an XP machine at the moment.

Answer (score 8):

Clear the entries in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU`

Edit: AutoComplete in the Run box is set in (of course) Internet Explorer's settings (Content Tab / AutoComplete): there's a button to Delete Autocomplete History. If that doesn't work, you could try turning AutoComplete off, rebooting, and turning it on again.

Comment: This gives me the list of the last run items (which I had already disabled), not the auto-complete cache.

Answer (score 2):

At least on Windows 8 the auto-complete history you are looking for is at
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\TypedPaths`

A solid state OS drive and NirSoft's [RegScanner](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) and you're set to find anything in the registry quickly.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it the following way:

1. Get SysInternal's [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)
2. Filter to "Explorer.exe" as the process/file
3. Execute `Win+R`
4. See what is happening in Process Monitor (I assume that some registry/files are involved)
5. See whether you can delete those found entries/contents.

**Update**

Seems others have better answers than I, please see those for a direct solution to your question.

Comment: +1 for a nice answer, inspired by Mark Russinovich no doubt!

Comment: I tried doing this but filtering Explorer.exe left me with 33.405 things to look at and to be quite honest I didn't really know what to do after that. I tried Win+R and typing some stuff but didn't notice any changes :(

Answer (score 1):

I just found out the answer on my Windows 10 machine, booting from a Linux liveCD and doing a grep search.

It's in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent`.

Answer (score -3):

I know that this topic is old, but if someone still wants to know where to clean this, it resides in Internet Explorer temporary files... amazingly! ¬_¬

Comment: And what is the path for the specific folder? Please see [answer] and take our [tour].