# Enable "Run" box cache in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, run-dialog

I have a question that is the opposite of [Clear Windows "Run" box cache](https://superuser.com/questions/287988/clear-windows-run-box-cache/287989): since upgrading to Windows 10 version 1809 on my machine, the "Run" box has stopped caching the commands I type.

Previously, and on other machines, I hit Windows+R to open the "Run" box, where I type a command to execute. The next time I open the Run box, previous commands appear there and can be found by scrolling or starting to type.

Now, on this machine, the Run box always comes up empty and I have to type all commands completely each time.

Does anyone know how to re-enable that cache?

In my searches, I have found many pages talking about how to clear this cache, but none to help me enable it.

Comment: Hum, browsing the run-dialog tag, I found https://superuser.com/questions/1196749/since-installing-windows-10-creators-update-version-1703-history-dialog-in-ru which might answer my question. `Show most used apps` is greyed out, so I'll ask my sysadmins if they can change the policy as spelled out in that question.

Comment: Never mind, answered here: https://superuser.com/a/1198259/988912